# Open Layers 3 with bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, momentjs, bootstrap-modal, openlayers-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using [bootstrap datetimepicker](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker) and [momentJs](http://momentjs.com/) with OpenLayers 3 so that when I select a new date it makes a request to get new geoJson data with specific parameters into a new vector source.

In my OL map I have multiple layers which need to be updated with the new data once the date is selected. In order to do this, I have created a "new vector source" which gets the correct data based on the date selected.

I need to setSource to all my layers everytime a new date is selected but I can figure out how to do this.

Here is my code:

```
var newSource = function(newDate){
   url: pathToUrl+newDate,
   format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
   projection: 'ESPG:3857'
}

var layers = map.getLayers();

$('.date-time-picker').datetimepicker({
    initialDate: new Date()
}).on('change', function(evt) {
   var newDate = moment(evt.date).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH');
   for (var i = 0; i < layers.length;i++) {
      return layers[i].setSource(newSource(date));
   }
});
```

This code is not really working, I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: h.Bd is not a function`

If I do this, I will be able to update the source on just one layer, how can I update the source on all the layers? Do I create a layer group? why is my loop not working?

```
$('.date-time-picker').datetimepicker({
    initialDate: new Date()
}).on('change', function(evt) {
   var newDate = moment(evt.date).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH');
   return map.getLayers().item(1).setSource(newSource(newDate));
});
```

**UPDATE: How I got it to work**

```
var newSource = function (newDate) {
   return new ol.source.Vector({
      url: pathToUrl + newDate,
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
      projection: 'ESPG:3857'
   });
}

$('#map-time-picker').datetimepicker({
   format: "yyyy/mm/dd hh:ii",
   initialDate: new Date(),
   minView: 'day',
   autoClose: true
}).on('changeDate', function (evt) {
    // New date is selected and formated correctly (global var)
    newDate = moment(evt.date).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH') + ':59';

    // Get layer group
    map.getLayers().forEach(function (layer, i) {
        if (layer instanceof ol.layer.Group) {
            // Get all layers inside this group
            layer.getLayers().forEach(function (sublayer, j) {
                // Add a new source (and url) to load in the map
                sublayer.setSource(newSource(newDate));
            })
        }
    });

   map.render()
});
```

Comment: Any ideas? I'm struggling to be able to get the layers array and return something like this for each layer (0 being the layer index): `map.getLayers().item(0).setSource(newSource(newDate));`

Comment: We could build a jsFiddle together, it sounds a bit confusing as it is.

Comment: Hi, just updated my initial question with my solution. The datepicker updates the url of the source and adds the new layer features into the map. My only remaining question would be if there should be a loader functionality in place to get new features async.

Comment: It's hard to "see" what you are doing. The thing can be clear to you but not here. Try to think as a dev who sees only what you post.